# notify2 - Error Message object has no attribute 'init'

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make an existing python project (taken from GITHUB) to work on windows 7.

The project is using notify2. I have downloaded the zip file from PyPI and renamed the file to notify2 and pasted in C:\Python34\Lib.

```
def sendmessage(title, message):
notify2.init("Test")
notice = notify2.Notification(title, message)
notice.show()
return
```

The above code is throwing Object has no attribute 'init'. Moreover, the notify2 package comes with few examples, even executing those example throw same error. How do i fix it. I am using Python 3.4.

Also, while installing notify2 using pip -

```
pip install notify2
```

i get error - failed:407 proxy Authorization Required. The message was followed by No Matching distribution found for notify2. Where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Install it this way:

in:
notify2-0.3.tar.gz\dist\notify2-0.3.tar\notify2-0.3\

you should have a *setup.py* file

In the command promote:

```
py -3 setup.py install
```

This should install it properly... also delete the things you put under *\Lib\ ...

Comment: I followed this article,https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html. Unpacked the folder, changed the directory to the unpacked notify folder and execute "python setup.py install". However I got an error at "import dbus", which I will download and install. However I wanted to understand your comment "in: notify2-0.3.tar.gz\dist\notify2-0.3.tar\notify2-0.3\". Can you please explain in detail what you meant by that statement.

Comment: Maybe you have dbus install on the another python version and you run setup.py on another one?

Comment: i have only one version of Python that is 3.4 and I checked Lib & Site-packages dbus is part of neither.

Comment: Try installing dbus(again?) and see if you can import it

Comment: I did install.  I downloaded from PyPI and placed the folder in LIB folder. After that I am able to install notify2 and even able to import dbus, but when I execute my program I get an error -     bus = dbus.SessionBus(mainloop=mainloop)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SessionBus'

Comment: Install dbus as you installed notify2  (py -3 setup install). don't put things under Lib ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101050/discussion-between-tushar-saurabh-and-yoav-glazner).

Comment: the reason I added dbus under Lib was because setup.py file was not present in dbus folder.